# NHibernate is not using the discriminator value to filter by subtypes, why?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have a domain model like this:

[image: Class diagram]

In the mapping, I am using a table-per-hierarchy structure  where all `LineItemOption` subtypes are stored in a single table and a named "OptionType" is used as a discriminator. This column isn't mapped to a property and isn't visible to the domain.

```
// FluentNHibernate ClassMap for LineItemOption
Map(lio => lio.Description);
DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("OptionType");

// FluentNHibernate SubclassMap for ColorOption
DiscriminatorValue("C")

// FluentNHibernate SubclassMap for GenericOption
DiscriminatorValue("O")
```

I am using the QueryOver API to fetch a list of `Order`s that contain a `LineItem` with a `LineItemOption` of a specific type containing a specific description.

```
private void AddColorRestrictionToQuery(
    IQueryOver<Order, Order> query,
    string color)
{
    query.JoinQueryOver<LineItem>(order => order.LineItems)
         .JoinQueryOver<LineItemOption>(line => line.Options)
         .Where(opt => opt.Description.IsLike(color))
         .Where(opt => opt is ColorOption);     // See below
}
```

This results in NHibernate adding "WHERE OptionType = *MyNamespace.Entities.ColorOption*" to the query. Instead of using the discriminator value, it seems to be using the fully-qualified namespace+class name.

Why is NHibernate using the class name instead of its discriminator?

Comment: This may not be possible with QueryOver, I assume this is a uni direction relationship, that is can you start from ColorOption type and work backwards?

Comment: @Rippo Yes, it's unidirectional. It's the `Order`s I'm interested in anyway, not the `LineItem`s attached to them.

Comment: Actually even in a bi-direction relationship this is impossible as you cannot start from ColorOption, unless you perform some ugly switching

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
query.JoinQueryOver<LineItem>(order => order.LineItems)
     .JoinQueryOver<LineItemOption>(line => line.Options)
     .Where(opt => opt.Description.IsLike(color))
     .Where(opt => opt.GetType() == typeof(ColorOption));
```